# Android requireActivity() on Adapter

Tags: android, kotlin

I need a help.

> requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
> 　　　　.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, testFragment)
> 　　　　.addToBackStack(testFragment.tag)
> 　　　　.commit()

TestFragment.kt
→worked

TestAdapter.kt
→didn't work
→requireActivity() seems to be unavailable.

What is the difference? And what should I do to display TestFragment in TestAdapter.kt?
There is a button for click in TestAdapter.kt. That's why I need to do this.

Comment: *What is the difference?* base class ? `requireActivity()` is a method of some class - it doesn't exists without this class

Comment: base class is different.
adapter's class is for ExpandableListAdapter.(maybe it dosen't matter)

Comment: > it doesn't exists without this class

→is it addable?

Comment: Or is there alternative plans?
For example, in this source file, convertView!!.findViewById<Button>(R.id.hogehoge) is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Adapter is not a Fragment, so it doesn't have the same functions available that Fragment does. If you need an Activity reference inside an Adapter (**which you shouldn't** because that is poor design--poor encapsulation), you need to add a constructor parameter or property to your class that allows you to pass an Activity reference to your Adapter. For example:

```
class ExpandableListAdapter(val activity: Activity): ListAdapter { //...
```

and then when you create it in your Fragment, you could pass `requireActivity()` as a constructor parameter.

But like I said, this would be poor encapsulation. Maybe you just need a `Context` reference for when you're creating view holders? In that case, you can get it from the `parent` parameter:

```
override fun createViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) {
    val context = parent.context
    // use context to create view holder's layout
}
```